# Geo Coder Error

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I am using geo coder class to find the address, but I, get a IOException with message, of "Service Not Available", How I can solve this problem.

Comment: What is your code? What is your error message? What are you tring? Please be specific when you ask.

Comment: You can solve this problem by fixing your code as to avoid the IOException.

Answer (score 1):

This is a know issue with the Emulator. It works fine on an actual device

On 2.2 API 8 you'll receive the following stacktrace

```
java.io.IOException: Service not Available
at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:117)
```

See here for more info (and a possible workaround) see the following URL :

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816

If you're having issues using the GeoCoder on lower APIs you should check the stacktrace. From time to time I'm having the following :

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server
at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:124)
```

This can be anything from a server-side issue at Google, or an issue on the client (internet connection).

If the GeoCoder returns an empty list, you need to check if you have a proper GeoCoder implementation available on the device (emulator or real phone).

This can be done using the isPresent() method on the Geocoder object.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Also, when running on an emulator, make sure your AVD image is setup with the Google APIs.

Comment: Thanks buddies for helping me, I have got the problem of emulator