# Find Address by latitude and Longtitude not by Geocoder.getFromLocation()

Tags: android

I have problem with how to get the address of the current location of the device in android 4.0.3.

In android v2.3 ~ < 4.0.3: I can get address by GeoCoder by method `getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)`, but in android 4.0.3, this method cannot work, causing the exception: `Services is not available`.

I know that some apps can get the address in 4.0.3, but I don't know how can they do that.
So please help me get the address by another method, or help me fix the exception: `Service is not available` from GeoCoder.

Answer (score 2):

> but in android 4.0.3, this method can not work, cause exception
>   "Services is not available".

This is common error that can occur on any platform.
Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894533/geo-coder-error)

> help me get address by another method

[Here](http://www.geonames.org/export/reverse-geocoding.html) is a list of web services that provide this function.

One of my Favorite is [This](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#findNearbyPlaceName)

Why dont you try hitting.

http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName?lat=18.975&lng=72.825833&username=demo

which returns following output.(Make sure you put your lat & lon in URL)

[image]

You can try this one too

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=19.172431,72.957019&sensor=false

Comment: Thanks @Vipul Shah. This very useful for me. But in this list web services, I still can't find which good enought to get address in Vietnam

Comment: oh, yes. I tried this service, but result not good enought as I want. The result is in my city, but it not near my place. Maybe it depends on country

Comment: http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName?lat=10.85669158&lng=106.62995028&lang=local&username=covisoft                                                                As you can see, this is the result of service when I set lat and log is my current location. But the distance is more than 20km from my place. If I set distance as parameter, it will return no result.

Comment: If it solved your problem then you can close this question by marking answer as accepted so it will be helpful for others who are facing similar issues.